# How to customize bootstrap subthemes in Drupal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, twitter, drupal-7

I'm testing the Bootstrap theme using Drupal 7.30, its awesome and all is ok, but if I want to create a custom page using tpl.php files like `customnamepage.tpl.php`, where can I put this kind of files and make them work in order to create my custom pages?

Comment: Here is a cool piece of documentation showing you how to set up a custom subtheme of Bootstrap: https://www.drupal.org/node/1978010 Please avoid to alter the Bootstrap theme's folders and files directly because if you make an update, you will lose all your code.

Comment: Thank you! great documentation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proper answer requires more information on which exact condition `customnamepage.tpl.php` should be used instead of the usual `page.tpl.php`.

As an example, if the system path to the page is `node/100` and you wanted to have a custom template only for this page, then you could define it in `page--node--100.tpl.php`. This works, if you have this file just somewhere in the bootstrap `theme` directory, but do remember to clear the cache before trying.

There are many ways to implement this, the best solution depends on the nature of the pages to which the customization should be applied.

Comment: Hi! sure that's the way im doing it, but the problems is; the page--node--100.tpl.php isnt work. That is the reason of the question, where should be located the file.tpl.php to make it work.

Comment: I tested yesterday that it works, for example, if you have the `.tpl.php` file just somewhere in the bootstrap theme directory subtree. Drupal does find it. Remember to clear the cache as always, and if you are using the `page--node--<id>` approach, make sure that the page is a node page and that the <id> matches the node id of the page. E.g., the Theme developer module can help you with naming the template file correctly.

Comment: Thanks, now it works! only need to follow the structure `page--node--<id>.tpl.php` and clear the cache as always. Thanks for your help!